# Which element of array changed in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `$watch` to get a callback when an array changes. Sending `true` for the third param will detect when any part of any element changes. But I need to know when and which item has been added or removed. Is there a better way of decoding added/removed element than just doing a manual comparison?

I would like to know whether an item was added or deleted and easily get a reference to the item.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a factory and then just watch a factory return property.  That would give you the chance to do some custom logic before directive reacts.  What is your specific reason for wanting to know what was added?  (Also check out [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/) if concerned about performance)

Comment: I didn't know you could watch a method - have only ever watched properties.

Comment: Yeah as long as it is a function with a return [see this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ldstGm1tNpqnocsqOEtQ?p=info).  (Be sure to NOT declare the method as a string though)

Comment: In that case, it's just watching the array. In my case, I would be watching something like factory.deleteElement(). To what would $watch be comparing my new return value?

Comment: Yes, watching factory.deletedElements() should return an array of deleted items then you can do what you will with that.  But this may get crazy.  You could also just $broadcast the deleted items and then in the directive use $on to catch it.  Why are you wanting to catch this information -- it lead to a better answer.

Comment: If you are looking for precise control over what data was updated, you can try looking into d3.  You can see what elements entered a dataset through enter, what elements changed through update, and what elements left through exit.